# Coalesce vs Case

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 5 fields which are bringing back a mixture of values and NULLS. For reporting purposes I need to replace any potential NULLS with a value. The database that I am interrogating is updated nightly via an SSIS package.

Obviously I will need to alter the .dtsx file to stop NULLS being brought through each day by adding some SQL.

My question is:

What is the most efficient way of dealing with these NULLS in terms of performance. So far ive identified `COALESCE` and `CASE` to deal with them and im leaning towards `COALESCE` because my alternative to `NULL` is not going to change, but I would be interested to hear if and why this would be the most efficient method.

Comment: I think the answer will be "it depends". Test out both with your systems and data, and find out for yourself! If both give relatively the same performance, go with the one you and your team feel most comfortable with.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`COALESCE()` is literally shorthand for a `CASE` statement, they will perform identically.

However, as podiluska mentioned, `ISNULL()` can be occasionally faster than a `CASE` statement, but it's likely to be a miniscule increase as these functions are very unlikely to bottleneck your procedure.

Read [here](http://dataeducation.com/performance-isnull-vs-coalesce/) more about the performance differences.

Answer (score 7):

In some circumstances, `ISNULL` is faster than `CASE` or `COALESCE`. However, if cross platform compatibility is an issue, `COALESCE` is ANSI standard.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer to use `COALESCE` over `CASE`. and the most interesting is the code is much shorter than using `CASE`.