# Canonical way to map null->false

Tags: sql

What is a canonical expression for the following:

```
NULL  -> false
false -> false
true  -> true
```

What I am using is:

```
select (foo is not null and foo)
```

which seems to work fine, but I'm wondering if there is a standard convention for this.

Comment: mysql has `COALESCE(foo, false)` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Comment: Methinks you probably have the most elegant solution - other solutions would tend to use vendor-specific methods/functions (e.g. coalesce) and therefore could not be considered universal convention.

Comment: btw +1 for the smart solution ;)

Comment: @raad my solution may be simplest for my example, but I still like `coalesce` for more complex boolean expressions, i.e. you can do `coalesce(foo or bar or baz, false)`

Comment: Actually `COALESCE` is far more widely available that I originally thought, so you're right - it is a good solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select coalesce(foo, false) from table
```

Answer (score 1):

I just looked it up. `COALESCE()` is ansi SQL.  So `SELECT (foo, false)` would give foo or false.

Answer (score 1):

If with canonical you means a standardized way, not DBMS/vendor-depending, then use CASE WHEN.

It is `ANSI`, and easy:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (foo is null) 
            THEN false 
            ELSE foo 
       END 
       AS YourStuff
...
```

Or `Coalesce` as stated in the other answers.

Their performance are identical: [Coalesce vs Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174399/coalesce-vs-case)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) or [`ISNULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

For MySQL you can also use [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

---

```
SELECT COALESCE(foo,false)
```

or

```
SELECT ISNULL(foo,false)
```

or

```
SELECT IFNULL(foo,false)
```