# Handle null and empty in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `c_name` column and a `name` column, would like get `c_name` if it isn't `null` or empty string.

I have tested the four SQL queries below. (SQL Server 2012)

- All queries will return `name` when `c_name` is a empty string.
- Only last query will return `name` when `c_name` is `null`.

If `null` is not equal to anything, why last statement will return correctly?

```sql
select case c_name when '' then name else c_name end as name from employee
select case ltrim(rtrim(c_name)) when '' then name else c_name end as name from employee
select case when ltrim(rtrim(c_name)) = '' then name else c_name end as name from employee
select case when ltrim(rtrim(c_name)) != '' then c_name else name end as name from employee
```

---

### Update

I test the first comment method, `isnull(nullif(c_name, ''), name)`, it can't  really return a complete name as expected. [`ISNULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) truncate your string as checking expression data type. Use [`COALESCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) instead.

Something about `COALESCE` and `CASE`: [sql - Coalesce vs Case - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174399/coalesce-vs-case/13179481#13179481)

```sql
select coalesce(nullif(c_name, ''), name) from employee
```

More interesting facts about empty string, seems I don't need to care about the how much the space in the string, so the `ltrim(rtrim())` seems can be removed. See [SQL Server 2008 Empty String vs. Space - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399844/sql-server-2008-empty-string-vs-space).

---

Some tests result below, or you can test by yourself in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ec32ea/14)

Suppose we use a table like this to test:

| c_name | name |
| --- | --- |
| *NULL* | name with c_name null |
|  | name with c_name empty |

```sql
select case c_name when '' then name else c_name end as name from employee
select case c_name when '' then name else c_name end as name from employee
select case when c_name = '' then name else c_name end as name from employee
```

These three statements will return the same result as:

| name |
| --- |
| *NULL* |
| name with c_name empty |

```sql
select case when c_name != '' then c_name else name end as name from employee
select coalesce(nullif(c_name, ''), name) from employee
```

Both these statements can return the expected result as:

| name |
| --- |
| name with c_name null |
| name with c_name empty |

```sql
select isnull(nullif(c_name, ''), name) as name from employee
```

This statement returns a truncated string.

| name |
| --- |
| name |
| name |

Comment: `isnull(nullif(c_name, ''), name)`

Comment: @DaleK but the last query, when `null` is not equal to empty string, I return `c_name`

Comment: @lptr this query result seems only return part of name string

Comment: @DaleK Yeah, I mean my logic return `c_name` for last query when not equal to empty string, but it will correctly return `name`

Comment: I see your confusion, null is not "equal" or "not equal' to a blank string. Thats why one should be very careful using a not equal or not in comparison when the values can include null - because its not necessarily the result one might expect.

Comment: Remember: **null does not mean "empty"**. Instead, it means "I don't know". So when you compare "I don't know" to an empty string, the result is still "I don't know"... it might be empty, it might not, and you can't tell until the value is populated. This is **also true for the opposite "not equals" check**: the answer is still "you don't know", which when forced to be treated as a conditional result is falsy. Lastly, for completeness, if you compare "I don't know" to another "I don't know", the answer is _still_ "I don't know".